# create floating div that does not overflow its parent div and has an invisible scroll bar using only CSS

Tags: css, scroll, responsive-design, css-float, overflow

I have been unable to find the answer on here, so I am hoping that someone can help me out. I am trying to get my floating div(.showme) to not overflow from the div with class, showher.  The divs will be within two other divs. Here is the HTML that I have written thus far:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hiddendiv.css">
    </head>

    <div class ="showher">
<a href="project.html"><img src="IMG.png">   
<div class="showme"><p>work, dammit. Okay, cool. It works, now to get the translucent background and the invisible scroll bar and to eliminate the white space between the images and keep this div from overflowing wihtout disrupting the other divs...maybe if I just allow a certain number of widows or orphans. idk. Overflow attribute does nothing and I think clear will put it below .container and .main</p></div></a>
</div>

<div class= "showher">
<a href="project.html"><img src="IMG.png">   
   <div class="showme">round 2</div></a>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
    .showme{ 
display: none;
color:#00AEEF;
margin: -10% -3% -3% 1%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

}

.showher{

border-collapse: collapse;
}

.showher:hover .showme{
display : block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by overflow? Do you want the text to dictate the height of its container?

Comment: No, I want the text div to be about half the size of the image div. what I mean be over flow is ....wait i think i might have figured part of it out. I still need to make an invisible scroll bar

Comment: apparently i am just going to have to make a different class for every single image on the page. I guess.